# How is a python function's name reference found inside it's declaration?

Tags: python

It's totally unexpected (to me at least) that `foo` would know `foo` inside of the function `def` for `foo`.  What the heck is going on here?

```
>>> def foo(x):
...   print "wow"
...   print globals().get('foo', 'sorry')
...   return foo
... 
>>> f = foo(3)
wow
<function foo at 0x10135f8c0>
>>> f
<function foo at 0x10135f8c0>
```

Is this some sort of effect of python's lazy evaluation?  It builds the function code first and puts it in `globals`, but then actually builds the function later when it's called?  Wow... what form of python magic is this?

Of course, this makes for ease of recursion... and was probably the reason this is in the language...

```
>>> def bar(x):
...   return bar(x)
... 
>>> bar(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in bar
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in bar
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in bar
  ...snip...
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in bar
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in bar
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: What do you mean with "but then actually builds the function later"? The function is already "built" (defined). I don't see any magic.

Comment: What language are you used to? Because I don't see any magic, neither with the recursion. What are you comparing this to?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How else would you do recursion? Why does that make infinite recursion easier than in any other language that supports recursion?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi:  Uhhh....?  Who said anything about other languages?

Comment: The interpreter reads `def bar(x)`, now it knows about `bar`...

Comment: @Evert: Python.  Yeah, it's build. Sure I see that. But explain how.

Comment: @WallyBeaver I guess I mean why is that example notable? How would you support recursion without allowing that?

Comment: Right.... I'm sure it's there b/c of the recursion.  But *HOW* is that implemented?

Comment: Python doesn't just "build a function", it's a staged process where it build a code object, then puts it on the stack, then builds a function only after it's called.  So it's some complex machinery going on.  What's the machinery to make `foo` available inside of `foo`?

Comment: @WallyBeaver There's no special machinery. Within the function, there's a bytecode instruction that will look up the name 'foo'. By the time the function is called, that name will resolve to the function.

Comment: clarified the question

Comment: Are you asking how the python interpreter creates a function in memory?

Comment: No, I'm asking the process that makes the name reference valid inside of the function definition... so that recursion is possible.  I realize there's bytecode under the hood, as noted in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing really mysterious.

There is, I believe a two pass aspect to this and you are doing a late evaluation in the body of the function.

update:  I qualified my explanation of what happens after the definition step - it looks as some things do happen with the function code **before** it gets called.  Wally's answer is better than mine in that respect.

Pass #1 - def foo(x) is found and set on the module's namespace.  Probably adds the function parameters as well.

<s>That's all, you don't drill down in the code.</s>

update:  Actually, I am not so sure about the code not being processed in some way **before** the call.  Looking at foo.func_code internals showed no great difference on before and after call.

Also, if you have a syntax error like parenthesis nesting or whitespace problems that does show up before even calling the function so something's picking that up ahead of the call.  See my code at the end.

I'll **guess** that the code is parsed but any variable resolution gets deferred until actual execution.

Pass #2 - you call foo(x), it is found and called.

The function's code gets executed for the first time.

When you hit globals()["foo"], it picks up the existing reference stored in #1.

You can also see some hints of this behavior when you run coverage.py or similar.  On import, all the outer definitions in a module are flagged as covered.

But the actual code only gets covered when you call it.

Another way to think of it is that you need that namespacing pass first to set up references, before proceeding further.  Otherwise, in my code below, foo would not find bar.

Here's some code I played to distinguish execution error vs syntax error...

```
def foo(x):
    """comment/uncomment to see behavior"""
    pass
    # return bar(x)   #this works

    return bar2(x)  #call time error

    #   return bar(x) bad whitespace  #IndentationError, nothing runs

print "foo defined"

def bar(x):
    return x*2


print "calling foo#1"

try:
    print foo(3)
except Exception, e:
    print e

#let's make it so there is a bar2...
bar2 = bar

print "calling foo#2"

try:
    print foo(6)
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `dis` can help...

```
>>> def foo(x):
...   print "wow"
...   print globals().get('foo', 'sorry')
...   return foo
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('wow')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       

  3           5 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (globals)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             11 LOAD_ATTR                1 (get)
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 ('foo')
             17 LOAD_CONST               3 ('sorry')
             20 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             23 PRINT_ITEM          
             24 PRINT_NEWLINE       

  4          25 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (foo)
             28 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

Hmm.  Complicated. So let's go simpler...

```
>>> def zap(x):
...   return zap
... 
>>> dis.dis(zap)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (zap)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

Yeah it looks like the bytecode is built, and hold instructions to load `zap` from `globals`.  So, the two-step process makes `zap` inside of `zap` not a special thing at all.

Let's see if we can dig into the process better and clarify...

```
>>> def blah(x):
...   def hlab(y):
...     return blah(x) 
...   return hlab
... 
>>> blah.func_code.co_consts
(None, <code object hlab at 0x10fcdfd30, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
>>> b = blah(4)
>>> b 
<function hlab at 0x10fce9c80>
>>> dis.dis(blah.func_code.co_consts[-1])
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (blah)
              3 LOAD_DEREF               0 (x)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(b)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (blah)
              3 LOAD_DEREF               0 (x)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> b_ = blah.func_code.co_consts[-1]   
>>> b.func_code
<code object hlab at 0x10fcdfd30, file "<stdin>", line 2>
>>> b_
<code object hlab at 0x10fcdfd30, file "<stdin>", line 2>
>>>
```

So it looks like the bytecode is built first, then the function is built from that... which then points back to the original bytecode.  I still don't see how it's hooked up, but I assume that's done on the "stack" somehow.  This process, at least, would make whatever name references used inside of the function `def` not special at all (i.e. irrelevant if `foo` uses `foo` or `blah` or `whatever`).

So ok, I get it.  Nothing special.

Although this is a bit odd...

```
>>> b(2)
<function hlab at 0x10faf9410>
>>> b(2)(2)
<function hlab at 0x10faf9578>
>>> b(2)(2)(2)
<function hlab at 0x10faf9410>
>>> _ is b(2)
False
```

...but I assume it's just cycling available memory addresses, or something like that.

Comment: wow, you originally asked this question and now you're getting all diggy with the internals already?  Impressed.  Tried to look at the func_code internals myselfl, but with just prettyprint and dir.  I didn't see any difference between before and after calling the function.  But there is definitely that 2 pass mechanism of first creating the references on the namespace and having them available to the code.

Comment: `Although this is a bit odd` - No, its not. At the beginning `b` has reference to `hlab` and when you invoke it with `b(2)`, `hlab` is called which actually calls `blah` with argument `2` and returns the value returned by it. So we are back to square one, because that is how we created `b` in the first place, by calling `blah` with an argument. So, the same thing repeats with `b(2)(2)(2)...`.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but then why is `b(2)(2)(2)` not `b(2)`?  I would expect that `id(b(2)(2)(2)) is id(b(2))` were that the case -- but the last statement seems to counter that.  Note that the first and third memory addresses are repeated -- are the objects not garbage collected as they are not assigned to a name?