# Compiling a tkinter game

Tags: python, compilation, compiler-errors, tkinter, pickle

I understand the general process of how to compile programs using py2exe, portable python, and other ways and always some of the issues that can cause problems such as matplotlib etc. However, I'm curious as to how a compiler would work if a game is using pickle. Would the game still be able to save and load states if it is compiled or would it no longer be able to have this option?

Also, if anyone doesn't mind I'm a bit confused as to how compiling a program actually works, as in the process that the compiler goes through to be able to make your program an executable a general explanation of this process would be awesome.

Comment: Have you used other language? If I believe correctly (WARNING! I MIGHT BE WRONG), Python compiles code when run or initialized while other languages, such as Java, have to go through an entire compiling process when the code is finished?

Comment: I have not I've been meaning to learn C++ but haven't had the time recently, python is the only language i've ever programmed in. I remember something vaguely similar to that. I know python can call code written in C, not sure if it can compile C.

Comment: I'm not too sure about that... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, python interprets the lines of code with the language parser... and then compiles the parsed lines to byte code.  This byte code is "compiled python".

Let's build a bit of code:

```
# file: foo.py 
class Bar(object):
  x = 1
  def __init__(self, y):
    self.y = y
```

Now we import it.

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo
<module 'foo' from 'foo.py'>
>>> reload(foo)
<module 'foo' from 'foo.pyc'>
```

What you'll notice is that the first time we import `foo`, it says it was imported from `foo.py`.  That's because python had to byte compile the code into a module object.  Doing so, however, leaves a `.pyc` file in your directory... that's a compiled python file.  Python prefers to use compiled code, as a time-saver as opposed to compiling the code again... so when you `reload` the module, python picks the compiled code to import.  Basically, when you are "installing" python modules, you are just moving compiled code into somewhere python can import it (on your `PYTHONPATH`).

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy
<module 'numpy' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.pyc'>
```

The `site-packages` directory is the default place that compiled 3rd party code gets installed.  Indeed a module is just a python object representation of a file.  Meaning, a module instance is a compiled file.  Once you "compile" the file in to a module, it's no longer going to care what's in the file... python only needs the compiled byte code after that.

```
>>> import types
>>> types.ModuleType.mro()
[<type 'module'>, <type 'object'>]
>>> foo.__class__.mro()
[<type 'module'>, <type 'object'>]
>>> i = object()
>>> object
<type 'object'>
>>> i
<object object at 0x1056f60b0>
```

Here we see (using `types`) that `foo` is an instance of a `ModuleType`... so basically a compiled file.  `mro` shows modules inherit from a python `object`, which is the primary object in python. (Yes, it's object-oriented).

Here `i` is an instance of an `object`, just as `foo` is an instance of a `ModuleType`.  Python works with instances of compiled objects, not the underlying code... just like (almost?) every other language.  So, when you work with a class that you built in the `foo` module, you are working with the byte compiled instance of the class.  You can dynamically modify the class instance, by adding methods on-the-fly... and it doesn't change the underlying file `foo.py`... but it does alter the byte-compiled instance of the module `foo` that's held in memory.

```
>>> zap = foo.Bar(2)
>>> zap.x, zap.y
(1, 2)
>>> foo.Bar 
<class 'foo.Bar'>
>>> foo.Bar.mro()
[<class 'foo.Bar'>, <type 'object'>]
>>>        
>>> def wow(self): 
...   return self.x + self.y
... 
>>> wow(zap)
3
>>> foo.Bar.wow = wow
>>> foo.Bar.wow(zap)
3
>>> zap.wow()
3
```

Again, the file `foo.py` would be unchanged... however, I added `wow` to the class `Bar`, so it's usable as if `wow` were in the code in the first place.  So working with "compiled" python is not static at all... it just means that you are working with code that has been byte compiled to save some time when you are importing it the first time.  Note that since the module `foo` is an instance, you can also edit it in memory (not just objects that already live in it's contents).

```
>>> foo.square = lambda x:x**2
>>>            
>>> from foo import square
>>> square(3)
9
```

Here I added `squared` to `foo` -- not to `foo.py`, but to the byte compiled copy of `foo` that lives in memory.

So can you pickle and unpickle objects in compiled code?  Absolutely.  You are probably doing that already if you've used `pickle`.

P.S. If you are talking about building C++ extensions to python, and compiling the code to shared libraries... it's still fundamentally no different.

If you are looking for some nitty-gritty details on byte compiling, check out my question and answer here: [How is a python function's name reference found inside it's declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129057/how-is-a-python-functions-name-reference-found-inside-its-declaration/28130023#28130023).