# When does my function will go to previous scopes to look for a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, local, python-nonlocal

in python 3.0 from what i know when i'm using variables that aren't found in the local scope it will go all the way back until it reaches the global scope to look for that variable.

I have this function:

```
def make_withdraw(balance):
    def withdraw(amount):
        if amount>balance:
            return 'insuffiscient funds'
        balance=balance-amount
        return balance
    return withdraw

p=make_withdraw(100)
print(p(30))
```

When i insert a line:

```
nonlocal balance
```

under the withdraw function definition it works well,
but when i don't it will give me an error that i reference local variable 'balance' before assignment, even if i have it in the make_withdraw function scope or in the global scope.

Why in other cases it will find a variable in previous scopes and in this one it won't?

Thanks!

Comment: Python won't let you *assign to* (i.e. `name = ...`) names it finds in outer scopes, unless you explicitly mark them `global`/`nonlocal`. It will let you *access* them, though (e.g. `... = name`).

Comment: There are some interesting (related) details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129057/how-is-a-python-functions-name-reference-found-inside-its-declaration/28130023#28130023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many questions on this topic. You should search before you ask.

Basically, since you have `balance=balance-amount` in function `withdraw`, Python thinks `balance` is defined inside this function, but when code runs to `if amount>balance:` line, it haven't seen `balance`'s definition/assignment, so it complains `local variable 'balance' before assignment`.

`nonlocal` lets you assign values to a variable in an outer (but non-global) scope, it tells python `balance` is not defined in function `withdraw` but outside it.